# Glassfish 3.1.2.2: admin console won't load

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, admin, application-server

When I try to access the admin-console with

```
http://localhost:4848
```

it says the admin console is loading, but it won't go further. If I refresh the the page as advised, I get a HTTP 404.

There are several other answered questions on Stack Overflow with similar issues, but none of the answers helped. So I set the global logging-level to FINEST and looked at the server.log.

The first and most prominent exception I get is:

```
[#|2013-05-07T11:04:52.187+0200|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminConsoleAdapter|_ThreadID=81;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminConsoleAdapter;MethodName=initRest;|java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://0.0.0.0:4848/management/domain
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1625)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminConsoleAdapter.initRest(AdminConsoleAdapter.java:557)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.AdminConsoleAdapter$1.run(AdminConsoleAdapter.java:372)
```

([here the complete log from starting glassfish to accessing admin-console](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73928414/server.log))

This happens on my development machine (Windows XP). Tried several re-installations to different locations. My JVM is from JDK 7u21.

This does not happen on my other development machine (Ubuntu 13.04) with similar configuration. The main difference - apart from OS - is the proxy-configuration. It is set to a proxy for all protocols, port 8080, except localhost.

I'm really out of answers myself...

**EDIT**

Additional weird behaviour. At times (every second restart of glassfish) it is possible to access to login to the admin console via

```
http://127.0.0.1:4848/j_security_check
```

I may then log in and edit any setting there. When I log off I get a HTTP 500:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'sun_html53'.

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while attempting to process a 'beforeCreate' event for 'sun_html53'.

root cause

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: REST Server Name not set!
```

After that I cannot login anymore via the above trick until restart of glassfish.

Also at time access via

```
http://localhost:4848/login.jsf
```

is possible, but then I may not alter any value but get directly a log error that says the same as above.

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:4848` instead .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Tried. Same result.

Comment: Wow.... I tried @Raptor solution and it worked.. Thats really strange.

Comment: @MethodMan for your case, it's because `localhost` not mapping to `127.0.0.1`. Check your HOSTS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good afternoon !!!!

I had the same exact problem the publisher described, and tried everything !!!, but after having feedback from different friends, I did the next steps:

Before starting... my environment was working OK (everything, if possible was installed in 64bits), until some web page required 32bits JRE, I downloaded it and installed it, after this, glassfish just went crazy and started doing what is described in this discussion. 
I did lots of test, installing, uninstalling, unzipping and deleting JDK, Glassfish versions.... nothing worked until one friend told to search in the users (due to thar every version of glassfish just crashed) folder; In here I searched for every folder names "java" or "Oracle" and I found in the route:

- C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment

The file "deployment.properties", Inside I found a properties:

```
1. deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe
2. deployment.javaws.jre.1.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe
```

Then I deleted property 1

```
(deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe)
```

and modified property 2 to:

```
+ deployment.javaws.jre.0.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\javaw.exe
```

That just resolved the problem !!
Hope this can help you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you ened up solving the situation.
I came here having the exact same problem.

After reading here, I could access the admin gui using the link you gave. I saw that one portlet that I deployed as an application was causing the havock.
Undeployed the "portlet" and everything was ok again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your glassfish installation.

These lines in your log:

```
[#|2013-05-07T11:04:59.953+0200|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext;MethodName=file;|PWC4451: File cannot be read D:\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\install\applications\__admingui\WEB-INF\classes\com\sun\webui\jsf\component\Label.class|#]

[#|2013-05-07T11:04:59.953+0200|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext;MethodName=file;|PWC4451: File cannot be read D:\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\install\applications\__admingui\WEB-INF\classes\com\sun\webui\jsf\component\CheckboxGroup.class|#]

[#|2013-05-07T11:04:59.968+0200|FINE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext|_ThreadID=82;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext;MethodName=file;|PWC4451: File cannot be read D:\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\install\applications\__admingui\WEB-INF\classes\com\sun\webui\jsf\component\RbCbSelector.class|#]
```

indicate that the files for the glassfish admin GUI can't be loaded...you'll have to fix this.

Maybe there is something wrong with your user permissions.

Comment: Good advice, but I don't know what to do about this.Everything runs under the same admin-user here in Windows. I checked the filesystem, everything is readable by everyone. I compared the content of `D:\glassfish3\glassfish\lib\install\applications\__admingui\WEB-INF\ ` with all current Glassfish-releases (web profile & full, ml and not ml). The directory is complete. There is a JAR unter `WEB-INF/extras ` with the needed classes: `webui-jsf-4.0.2.9.jar `.